# Touch Down Event for Tap Gesture Recognizer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am building an app and I am using an image view as a button, I use  a tap gesture recognizer to run an action when the button is tapped. How would I set it so that instead of the gesture recognizer using the touch down inside method it has uses the Touch Down method?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380389/ios-detect-user-touch-release